# Dynamic Namespace for Input XML

Tags: xslt, xpath, namespaces

I have searched many posts on dynamically setting namespaces but they all seem to refer to setting the namespace of the output XML.

The issue I have is that the namespace (defined at root and same for all child nodes) of the input XML differs, and the same stylesheet needs to be able to handle both inputs.

For example, one input XML is:

```
<root xmlns="aaa">
    <body>xxx</body>
</root>
```

And the other input XML is:

```
<root xmlns="bbb">
    <body>yyy</body>
</root>
```

In the stylesheet, my XPath obviously needs to use the defined namespace, which is declared with a prefix, i.e.:

```
xmlns:one="aaa"
```

But as soon as the second input XML is being transformed, it of course fails to work.

I could define another namespace, e.g.

```
xmlns:two="bbb"
```

But the only way to use that namespace at the right time is to duplicate all the XSLT code and have the other namespace as the prefix for all the XPath (even then I would still need to identify which set of XPath to use which may be fun..)

My stylesheet currently uses the following XPath:

```
%lt;SOMETHING&gt;
<xsl:value-of select="one:body" />
%lt;/SOMETHING&gt;
```

As you can see it uses the "one" namespace prefix. Is there any way to just get the value of either "body" tag, regardless of namespace? As mentioned in a comment below, although I appreciate they are different elements based on namespace, I know that the information in each will be the same so I can treat them as such.

I have seen posts on using xsl:element with a namespace attribute but from what I can tell that just defines the namespace of the output XML, not the input. (To make matters worse, what I am outputting is actually escaped XML, e.g. %lt;SOMETHING> so I couldn't use xsl:element anyway).

My current solution (since posting this) is to have two extra stylesheets included in the main stylesheet. Each one is specific to either namespace "one" or namespace "two", each line of XPath uses the relevant namespace prefix.

I am hoping there is a way to avoid having two separate stylesheets that are almost identical except for the namespace prefix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apart from showing the input documents, please also show the _output_ you expect from the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, you want to process the XML ignoring the elements' namespaces. Actually, the sense of namespaces is to distinct between elements from different contexts. So from an XML point of view, `<one:body>` has absolutely nothing to do with `<two:body>`, besides the fact that they happen to have the same name.

If you want to do it anyway, instead of:

```
<xsl:template match="one:body">
<xsl:template match="two:body">
```

you should match on the elements' local name only:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='body']">
```

In order to give a little more background: If you say

```
<xsl:template match="one:body">
```

then this is only a short notation of

```
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='aaa'][local-name()='body']">
```

(i.e. "*match any element whose namespace is 'aaa' and whose name is 'body'*")

Thus, ignoring the namespace by leaving away the

```
[namespace-uri()='aaa']
```

makes it

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='body']">
```

Instead, you had better say

```
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='aaa' or namespace-uri()='bbb'][local-name()='body']">
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='aaa' or namespace-uri()='bbb' or namespace-uri()='ccc'][local-name()='body']">
```

and so on. **If**, as dret states, you know all possible namespaces in advance.

Comment: This is not a good answer. Namespaces are presumed to be there for a reason. Ignoring them is not good practice.

Comment: Ignoring namespaces may not be good practice, but as I got it, this is what Neil Belch asked for.

Comment: The way I understand the question, he wants to treat two **known** namespaces the same way- which is not the same as treating **any** namespace in the same manner.

Comment: That was only an example he gave.

Comment: Ignoring them does sounds like an option, unfortunately we are writing stylesheets for a system we don't have much control over so we may have to defy convention to get around things.
I appreciate what you say that the same element name in a different namespace is a different element altogether, but for my purposes they contain the same information.
However - how would using the local-name function work within XPath definitions? I have edited my question to hopefully provide more detail on what I mean.

Comment: FYI, you can also use https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-namespace-uri-from-QName to find out namespace URIs at runtime. This means that at runtime, you can inspect both the local name, and the namespace URI of any element. It depends on your requirements which of those matters to you, and needs to be inspected. But as people said: ignoring namespace URIs and blindly using local names goes against very basic XML ideas, indicates an XML pipeline that is broken, and also means that at some future point in time, things may break badly and may be hard to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you define both namespaces, then use paths such as:

```
one:body | two:body
```

to address the elements in the source XML.

---

For example, instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="one:body" />
```

use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="one:body | two:body" />
```

Comment: much better than just using local names but only works if the namespaces to be expected are known in advance (and there are not too many).

Answer (score 0):

As I already wrote! Instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="one:body" />
```

you can write

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='body']" />
```

Or, if you have XPath 2.0, then

```
<xsl:value-of select="*:body" />
```

Comment: This looks like the most promising solution - I appreciate it isn't the best practice one but I can make assumptions e.g. two tags called "body" in the different namespaces can be treated as having the same data.
Once I've tested I will feedback/accept/etc, thanks.